# PHP code run in terminal but not working in chrome

Tags: php

I have used [pdf-to-image](https://github.com/spatie/pdf-to-image) to build my new package. and I got some problem here:

```
<?php
// die(echo getenv('HOME'););
require_once(__DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php');

$fileone = realpath('demo.pdf');
$pdf = new Spatie\PdfToImage\Pdf($fileone);
$pdf->saveImage(__DIR__.'upload/');
?>
```

I required it into index file but I can't run this code on Chrome but it working when I run by terminal, how can I fix it?

**UPDATE** Adding error shared in comments:

> Fatal error: Uncaught ImagickException: Failed to read the file in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pdf2Image/vendor/spatie/pdf-to-image/src/Pdf.php:44 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/pdf2Image/vendor/spatie/pdf-to-image/src/Pdf.php(44): Imagick->__construct('/opt/lampp/htdo...') #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/pdf2Image/index.php(6): Spatie\PdfToImage\Pdf->__construct('/opt/lampp/htdo...') #2 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pdf2Image/vendor/spatie/pdf-to-image/src/Pdf.php on line 44

Comment: Did you get an error ?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught ImagickException: Failed to read the file in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pdf2Image/vendor/spatie/pdf-to-image/src/Pdf.php:44 Stack trace: #0 /opt/lampp/htdocs/pdf2Image/vendor/spatie/pdf-to-image/src/Pdf.php(44): Imagick->__construct('/opt/lampp/htdo...') #1 /opt/lampp/htdocs/pdf2Image/index.php(6): Spatie\PdfToImage\Pdf->__construct('/opt/lampp/htdo...') #2 {main} thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/pdf2Image/vendor/spatie/pdf-to-image/src/Pdf.php on line 44
i got this error on chrome

Comment: Does the user that runs your PHP process (generally www-data) has access to this folder?